# Use Rails 5.1 API with VueJS2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, vue.js

I have an existing Rails app, that has a resource which renders out as json.  I've used Postman to check the json, and it's all good.

I've used the webpacker gem to install vuejs:

```
gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.0'
```

Then:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

Followed by:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install:vue
```

I then have the relevant new files in my app.

However I'm not getting the data to render in the index page.

**index.html.rb**

```
#other code removed
<div id="roastslist">

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Roast Name</th>
        <th>Roaster</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="roast in roasts">
        <td>{{roast.name}}</td>
        <td>{{roast.roaster}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
#other code removed
```

**assets/javascripts/roasts.js**

```
var v = new Vue({
  el: '#roastslist',
  data: {
    roasts: []
  },
  mounted: function(){
    $.get('/roasts.json', function(data){
      v.roasts = data;
    })}
})
```

Comment: How is your controller method passing to Vue?

Comment: Sorry not 100% sure what you mean. Very new to this. The only thing I have added is `format.json { render index: @roasts }`

Answer (score 0):

It's really quite simple, though unfortunately not documented:

1. Get rid of webpacker (unnecessary headache, see below)
2. Use vue [from the cdn](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html). It's cached and you have no work with it.
3. move your js code into the template
4. Render your data into the template
   5 (optional) update the data from the json endpoint if (and only if) it changes

To demonstrate, this would be the code in your template (I use haml, it has a :javascript filter)

```
:javascript
   var v = new Vue({
       el: '#roastslist',
     data: {
       roasts: "#{@rosts.to_json}"
     }
```

The to_json renders the roasts (as json) and thus makes them available to Vue. to_json has many options (like :only) but if that is not enough, i use rabl.

If (and when) your js code get's too much, you can move some into different files, or (functions) into the asset pipeline.

PS: I use [ruby2js](https://github.com/rubys/ruby2js/wiki/Vue), which reduces the code size by about half (while being easy on the eye)
Also, watch [my blog,](https://medium.com/webdev-camp/tagged/vuejs) i'm about to write more on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Vue's mounted, try JSON.parse as your data like so:

```
 var element = document.getElementById('roastslist')
  if (element != null) {
    const v = new Vue({
      el: element,
      data: {
        roastslist: JSON.parse(element.dataset.rosts)
      },
      template: "<roast-list :original_roasts='roastslist' />"
    })
  }
})
```

Then, in your roasts.js use:

```
 <tr v-for="roast in original_roasts">
    <td>{{roast.name}}</td>
    <td>{{roast.roaster}}</td>
  </tr>
```

I changed roasts to original_roasts to signify the passed json object. Also, original_roasts could be passed as a prop array in other components using the same json data.